# AngularJS - Add Select model option in Json string

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-select

**HTML**

```
<form ng-submit="exportVideoForm()">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="exportvideo.exportName" required>

    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="exportvideo.description" required>

    <select class="form-control" name="selectposition" id="selectposition" 
          ng-options="position.name for position in data.waterMarkImgPosition track by position.id"
          ng-model="data.selectedPosition"
          ng-change="changePosition(data.selectedPosition)"
          required>
    <option ng-show="false" value="">Please Select</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

**Ctrl**

```
$scope.exportVideoForm = function() {

        $scope.data.selectedPosition.id = 'lowerLeft';
        $scope.exportvideo = $scope.exportvideo.push($scope.data.selectedPosition.id); //push watermark position in json string
        $scope.exportVideoJson = angular.toJson($scope.exportvideo); //convert to json

};
```

**Output**

```
console.log($scope.exportVideoJson) = {"exportName":"myname","description":"mydesc"}
```

When I try to `concat/push` position.id, it throws exception
**Error: $scope.exportvideo.push is not a function**

How do I add position.id value to existing json string ?

Answer (score 0):

Push is for appending items to an array. Looks like you want to add a property to a json object. Just do

```
$scope.exportvideo.id = $scope.data.selectedPosition.id;
```

Comment: For multiple properties, do I need to assign like this only ? Any other alternative ?

Comment: You could also do $scope.exportvideo['id'] = $scope.data.selectedPosition.id;

Comment: I meant what if this also needs to be added `$scope.videoFormat = $scope.data.selectedFormat.id ?